# Bash - Replacing random number between quotes

Tags: bash, awk, sed, string, random

I've created a script which writes .flame/XML-like files, containing within them, a string which looks like:

```
scale="n"
```

where *n* is a random number, with a variable number of digits. What I am attempting to do is replace this string with another random number within a particular range; generating this number is trivial, as I already have *shuf* working for this purpose. The trouble arises when attempting to find and replace this string, as it could be similar to any of the following:

```
scale="54.1948", scale="182.55816", or scale="3.59"
```

I've tried using *sed* for this, and while I'm confident it's possible, I have not found the correct syntax. The occurrence of this string is not consistent between files.

Ideally, the command I am looking for would convert a string which looks like this:

```
scale="54.1948" or scale="3.59"
```

to one which looks like:

```
scale"254" or scale="579"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the file in fact an XML file? In that case one could possibly do it with XMLstarlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is `sed -e 's/\(scale=\)"[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?"/\1"'"$replacement_number"'"/'`. The search regex in detail:

```
\(scale=\)        the literal string scale=, remembered as \1
"                 opening double quote
[0-9]\+           one or more digits
\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?   optionally, a period followed by one or more digits
"                 closing double quote
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler and more generalized solution.  Extended sed syntax (`-e`) and back-references are not used for this solution.

This replaces everything between the double quotes with the number `$n`.

The basic `sed` command looks like this:

```
s/scale="[^"]*"/scale="$n"/
```

The expression `[^"]*` matches zero or more non-double-quote characters.  After quoting, the `shell` command looks like this:

```
sed "s/scale=\"[^\"]*\"/scale=\"$n\"/"
```

If you want to change only the `scale` values which contain numbers and decimal points only, you could use someting like this:

```
s/scale="[.0-9]*"/scale="'$n"/
```

There's usually a trade off between input checking vs readability and maintainability.